# Sample of **Complete** Google Plus API User Object

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I know what is the full structure of Google Plus API user object. I found the structure from this documentation: https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/plus/v1/python/latest/plus_v1.people.html#get

But I want a real sample. Not just an incomplete sample, but a sample where each field is filled. So I can be sure on how to handle the data. Even Larry Page, the Google's co-founder, don't fill his Google Plus profile completely.

If anyone has the full sample, even just the ID that I can GET request on my own, that will be helpful.

Thanks all!

Comment: Kinda sounds like you need to play with it. The best learning experience is practice.

Comment: Yup, it seems so. Maybe I should just collect as much sample JSON user object as I can and analyze it all.